# Convert TCanvas.Pie coordinates to GDI+ DrawPie

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, gdi+

I need to create a procedure e.g:

```
procedure GdiPie(Canvas: TCanvas; X1: Integer; Y1: Integer; X2: Integer; Y2: Integer; X3: Integer; Y3: Integer; X4: Integer; Y4: Integer);
var gr: TGPGraphics;
begin
  ...
  gr.DrawPie(brush, X1, Y1, X2 - X1, Y2 - Y1, ???) // calculate "startAngle, sweepAngle"
end;
```

That takes the same parameters as [`TCanvas.Pie`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_Pie.html) and convert to `TGPGraphics.DrawPie` which expects parameters:
`x, y, width, height, startAngle, sweepAngle`

`X1,Y1,X2,Y3` are easy. 
But, how can I calculate `startAngle, sweepAngle` given  `X3,Y3,X4,Y4`?

I have found this link: [How to create a pie chart](http://delphidabbler.com/tips/148). but still I can't seem to "reverse" it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate start and end angle using these formulas:

```
CX := (X1 + X2) / 2; // center of bounding rectangle
CY := (Y1 + Y2) / 2;
aStart := ArcTan2(Y3 - CY, X3 - CX);
aEnd := ArcTan2(Y4 - CY, X4 - CX);
 SweepAngle := aEnd - AStart
```

Don't forget about ArcTan range and possible `+-2*Pi` offset of SweepAngle (calculated as difference)

One more approach (through dot and cross vector products):

```
SweepAngle := ArcTan2((X3 - CX) * (Y4 - CY) - (X4 - CX) * (Y3 - CY),
                      (X3 - CX) * (X4 - CX) + (Y3 - CY) * (Y4 - CY));
```

It seems you need angles in degrees, so apply `RadToDeg` function.

Comment: This produces different results than TCanvas.Pie. I used `aStart` as `startAngle`

Comment: I have changed `aStart := RadToDeg(ArcTan2(Y3 - CY, X3 - CX))` and the same for `aEnd := RadToDeg(ArcTan2(Y4 - CY, X4 - CX))`. works link a charm! thanks.